# Why is the Loki library not more widely used?

Tags: c++, boost, c++-loki

The [Loki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_%28C%2B%2B%29) library implements some very widely used concepts (smart pointer, visitor, factory, etc.). The associated book "Modern C++ Design" is often mentioned, but the library itself is not widely used. Why is that?

Most developers seem to prefer Boost. In particular, why do people often decide to use Boost's smart pointers rather than Loki's?

Comment: No-one needs a smart pointer with 6 template parameters.

Comment: Loki infamously couldn't be compiled by any mainstream compiler when it was published.  Alexandrescu is a smart dude.  Too smart for me.

Comment: @johannes: Most of the template params have default values, so you don't have to set them. And you could just use typedef to bind some of the template params.

Comment: Actually Frank, you notably *can't* use a typedef to bind *some* of the template parameters -- as of C++03 typedefs must specify *all* template parameters.

Comment: @ribond: Oh right, I forgot that you cannot have templated typedefs. A real language failure, I think. (Although I know there are workarounds.)

Comment: Maybe that's because there aren't many compilers that support loki to it's fullest... Also on a side note, always having a dependency on something like boost and loki, might not be a good thing, if something is missing it should be added to the standard library, even if it is an extension of the library, that way you don't have to use that if you don't need it...

Comment: @Coyote21: in C++, there's a different philosophy around the Standard library compared to many other languages.  The contents are suitable for an overwhelming majority of uses, not hardcoding some arbitrary set of compromises that might only be good for a relatively small proportion of programs.  So, rather than including say an XML library or web server class, the programmer's expected to do a little work to find one that suits their needs.  That might be less convenient, but it discourages careless use of a poorly suited library and means you can really trust what is Standard.

Answer (score 20):

Loki is a research/proof-of-concept sort of thing. Alexandrescu pushes new ideas, other people adopt those for real world. Also `boost::shared_ptr` is almost literally in TR1.

Answer (score 18):

Loki's suffers from being a good library touching on several functional areas (template metaprogamming support with a few specific applications: smart pointers, singletons, function objects, scope guards etc.), whereas boost is a collection of many libraries typically exhaustively covering each functional area and much more highly tuned for portability (first).

When 9 birds out of 10 can be killed with the same stone, many people just start with boost and fill in the gaps with third party libraries.  It's very hard to compete with boost if you overlap.  Because you won't overlap with much of boost, people will download/install boost anyway to get the other functionality, so unless you nail an area that boost is weak at - and the difference is significant to the project, they'll "settle" for boost there too.

Further, Alexandrescu made repeated attempts to get Loki included in boost, and some of the key boost authors just weren't cooperative.  My personal view is that they want the more complete but much less user-friendly [MPL](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/) to have more "market share": as authors of the library and the hard-copy books that are the only decent documentation (in stark contrast with most other boost libraries which have excellent online documentation), they do quite well out of this.

If anyone is offended by and disagrees with this analysis, I'm all ears.

Another practical issue with extremely parameterised code is that in large projects where different developers/teams work independently, they'll often end up using subtly different instantiations of the same template pretty arbitrarily.  This makes it harder to pass values between those subsystems: the receiver may need to:

- be parameterised (i.e. templated, and hence inline, which introduces compilation dependencies and slower builds in enterprise-scale systems)
- provide some minimal coverage for all possible instantiations (e.g. checking error codes and expecting/handling exceptions)
- working through some compile-time to run-time hand-over based on an abstract base accessor with implementations for each instantiation) which compromises some of the performance benefits of parameterisation

This is all possible, but it takes a great programmer to navigate the terrain.

Comment: That's exactly the problem with boost, boost IS the C++ standard library or should be, since the current standard library doesn't suit anyone... That's why C++ is being dumped by languages like Java and C#, because of the highly rich standard library. Not to mention that both Java and C# allow one to plug in other libraries if they want to, since they have nice interfaces meant to be extendable.

Answer (score 12):

You want to use a library that the next programmer is going to know and that is going to be well supported in the future - so you pick a major lib.
Because it's a major lib lots of people use it, so it becomes the default choice.

Answer (score 7):

I actually prefer Loki's way of doing things and I have contributed to Loki myself a Decorator pattern which now sits in the tracker because the project as far as I know **is no longer maintained**.
I use boost shared_pointer just because it will be the standard very soon, I may dislike the fact that I can't customize it to act exactly the way I want it to act but I have to live with it.
Usage of the standard library is important as it keeps the code maintainable by other programmers. If it's open source and you want to experiment go ahead and use Loki. No one is stopping you.
Actually Windows Vista uses some of Loki's features.
I am guessing they are not using the redundant implementations of smart pointers and visitors.

Answer (score 4):

Speaking as someone who's used quite a bit of the Boost library, and also looked at Loki more than once, the biggest problem was the sparsity of documentation. Also, Loki uses some of the hairiest bits of C++ templates. Exciting stuff, but also rather daunting.

Comment: *"Loki uses some of the hairiest bits of C++ templates"* - so does Boost, or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: See the `shared_ptr` faq: *Parameterization discourages users. The shared_ptr template is carefully crafted to meet common needs without extensive parameterization. Some day a highly configurable smart pointer may be invented that is also very easy to use and very hard to misuse. Until then, shared_ptr is the smart pointer of choice for a wide range of applications. (Those interested in policy based smart pointers should read  Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu.)*

Comment: @litb: As I said on the IRC, I disagree. It just felt more natural to me to use the loki's smart pointer then boost's one. If I wanted mutex lock on loki's smart pointer I just needed to input a mutex class for it. Loki's smart pointer is the most generic solution I found to the problem. It sometimes makes the use easier.

Answer (score 3):

I used Loki once for a little tool (basically an interpreter) and actually liked it. My coworkers were less enthusiastic about the library, so its use remained constrained to this small sub-project.